# overlay is not working

Tags: css, html

My overlay of one div into another is not working.  When i click on login button it show ul . which is on back of another div which having background

Does anybody help me?

Here is website link here is link

and here is [image: Screenhot]

Comment: I already tried postition absoult in firebug

Comment: Please include the relevant ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)) code in your question, post a demo (if you'd like to do so, it's not obligatory) to a site for that purpose ([JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com) or similar) or, ideally, use the [Stack Snippets feature](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to post the live code in your question. Posting a link to your own site renders the question useless once you correct the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Add `z-index:9999` to `.navbar.navbar-fixed-top` in css</strike>

**edit**

Add this class to CSS `.region-topheader` and assign it `z-index:9999; position relative`

Answer (score 0):

It's problem with `z-index`. Try adding this css:

```
.navbar.navbar-fixed-top {
    z-index: 4;
}

.region.region-topheader {
    z-index: 8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your drop down has z-index of 1030 and baner has a z-index of more then 1030 thats the reason you are not able to see it, if you give your baner a z-index of 1000 then it should work.

Comment: <div role="banner" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" style="
    z-index: 1000;
">